# Writing and Reading data from RTC module EEPROM_Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, rtc

i have took below code from https://lastminuteengineers.com/ds1307-rtc-arduino-tutorial/. i am not understand what these codes are doing. please help me to understand.

```
Wire.write((int)(eeaddress >> 8)); // MSB
Wire.write((int)(eeaddress & 0xFF)); // LSB
```

Thanks

Comment: how many bits long is `eeaddress`?

Answer (score 1):

These two lines write a 16 bit (2 8-bit) value, which is signed -32768..32767 or unsigned 0..65535.

Assume a value in bits: 10101010 11001100

Statement 1:

```
Wire.write((int)(eeaddress >> 8)); // MSB
```

The first statement shifts the value 8 bits (positions) to the right; this is called the MSB (Most Significant Byte, the left 8 bits). Bits on the right are clipped / fall off. Thus

```
10101010 11001100
```

will become

```
00000000 10101010
```

When casted to an 8 bit value you get:

```
10101010
```

Statement 2:

```
Wire.write((int)(eeaddress & 0xFF)); // LSB
```

The second statement will get the LSB (Least Significant Byte). This used the AND operator, meaning a bit is only 1 if both values are 1. 0xFF is the 'mask'

```
Original value: 10101010 11001100
Mask:           00000000 11111111
                ----------------- AND (&) operator
Result:         00000000 11001100
```

As you can see only the right 8 bits are kept. When casting this to an 8 bit value:

```
11001100
```

Comment: Do you also know why there is an int cast (`(int)...`)?

Comment: @Gerben; actually I would either expect a 8 bit type cast (`uint8_t` or `int8_t`  cast as the result is always 8 bits, or no cast at all, as the caller probably expects an 8 bit variable. Even if the caller expects 16 bit (which would be unnecessary much), the 8 bit argument will automatically be casted to 16 bits, without a need for a cast in the two lines provided in this code.

Comment: Thank you. Seems like the Wire library will [cast it (back) into an uint8_t](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/libraries/Wire/src/Wire.h#L82) anyways.

Comment: @Gerben, true, thus casting it within the calling `write` method is not needed.

Comment: Thanks @Michel Keijzers

Comment: If the answer helped you, upvote the answer (the arrow next to the answer). If the answer solves your problem, accept the answer (icon next to the answer).